# pure html - print text string as a script output

Tags: html, text

Have table in html page with images in table cells. Images are generated by script in following maner:

```
<img src="/cgi-bin/script_name">
```

Advantage of following way is the table is drawn as page is loaded, but images itself could load later/delayed. Looking for similar solution for text strings with no client side scripting, pure html only. Is it possible at all?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: The text would load instantly just like the table. I'm confused on what your asking?

Comment: Your question is very vague.  Are you saying you want text to load as the page loads?  This is default behavior.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of english: Want to call server side script to output text strings into table cells of my page. Scripts need some time to run, but table is imediatelly drawn in browser. I want to strings are displayed when source scripts terminating, with no matter of their positions in the table, adn do it without client side scripting. For images I can achieve this by linking script as a image source URL. Looking for similar solution for text strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client-side includes for partial content [was considered briefly](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7245/why-no-client-side-html-include-tag). The accepted answer suggests using an [`<iframe src="http://..">`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) but I wouldn't fill a table with dozens of them.

I highly recommend a lightweight [AJAX implementation](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) with a sprinkling of Javascript.

If your clients can't support Javascript for some reason then I would look to the server to have content ready in a timely fashion. Perhaps cache or pre-load scripted content.